# Reading content from file in Rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

I have generated a file (i.e test.html) which I want to send in a mail. How can I read it's content in mailer and then shoot a mail.

Comment: Do you want to send the file as an attachment or as the email's HTML content?

Comment: As the email content. @Stefan

Comment: See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#create-a-mailer-view